# validate comma list of one alpha letter per list item with javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to validate a comma list of letters from A up to the letter L, all caps. I could probably write something to loop the list and make sure each item has exactly one letter from A-L but I'd prefer to use a regex. Is this possible?

Valid:

```
A, G, F
```

Invalid:

```
Ab, G, F, Car
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to validate your input of letters `A-L` separated by comma:

```
/^[A-L](?:\s*,\s*[A-L])*$/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iQ3tJ6/1)

**Breakup:**

```
^          # line start
[A-L]      # match letters [A-L]
(?:        # start non-capturing group
  \s*      # match 0 or more white-spaces
  ,        # match a comma
  \s*      # match 0 or more white-spaces
  [A-L]    # match letters [A-L]
)*         # end non-capturing group, * makes this group match 0 or more times
$          # line end
```

Comment: I tested this and it works as well as the one I just wrote, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I actually answered my own question shortly after posting this. The following Regex works:

```
^(?!,)(,?\s?[A-L])+$
```

Allows only one char per item, uppercase, spaces optional, no end comma.

Thanks for any other answers, I'm sure there are many ways to accomplish this.

[regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/xJ5zU0/1)

Comment: I didn't downvote but it will validate `ABCD` aa a valid input.

Comment: you are correct. the answer you posted is accurate. i will mark as answer

Answer (score 0):

Why are you giving up on array manipulations? They could be quite elegant.

```
'A, G, F'.split(', ').every(x => x.length === 1 && x >= 'A' && x <= 'L')
```

Comment: you downvoted me for this? you could have just answered my question, I asked for regex.